# Type argument is not within its bounds Expected: Any Found: String

Tags: android-studio, generics, kotlin

Given

```
open class BaseClass<T: Any>(...) { ... }

class MySubclass<String>(...) : BaseClass<String>(...) { ... }
```

I get the error

```
Type argument is not within its bounds 
Expected: Any 
Found: String
```

Android Studio offers me `Add 'kotlin.Any' as upper bound for String` which leads to

```
// Note the <String: Any> instead of <String>
class MySubclass<String: Any>(...) : BaseClass<String>(...)
```

But I don't understand why `<String>` isn't fine but `<String: Any>` is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to type just

```
class MySubclass(...) : BaseClass<String>(...) { ... }
```

Where you put `<String>` right after `MyClass`, you've defined a generic type for your subclass named `String`. And since it has the same name as the actual class `String`, it's confusing. Usually a single capital letter is used for a generic type. What you wrote would be equivalent to:

```
class MySubclass<T>: BaseClass<T>()
```

Which is not allowed because your type is possibly an `Any?`, which wouldn't satisfy the requirement that the type extend from non-nullable `Any`.

`<String: Any>` works because it's like defining a type `<T: Any>`, which enables it to fit your non-nullable requirement in the base class.